# How to escape an ItemGroup list of files with quotes - MSBuild

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have the following item group in my project

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Include="$(ProjectDir)\Test\**\*.test" />
</ItemGroup>
```

How can I escape these paths? I need them escaped so my exec command works. I include them within my command like so (but happy to alter if needed)

```
<Exec Command="$(xxx)xx.exe @(TestFiles, ' ')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `\\` instead of `\` in your path string.

Comment: Thanks for the response but the back sashes aren't the problem - it's that my path has spaces due to windows i.e. "Visual Studio 2017"